# NPM Issue with @types/d3 install from Oreilly book code

Tags: node.js, d3.js, npm

I'm doing a project for a coding class trying to use the example from the OREILLY book: building data visualizations with D3 and Angular 2.

Code is here from the book:
https://github.com/Matt-Dionis/realtime-angular2

This project is supposed to build a file that will generate the top 10 tweets for any given user-inputted value.

The code works great to push live tweets to my node server, but I'm having an issue with installing D3 and @types/d3

After installing: `npm install @types/d2 --save-dev` I get an error that: 
webpack: Failed to compile along with hundreds of lines or errors that all point to @types errors like the following first error:

> ERROR in /Users/steven/Documents/OneDrive/Coding/New Folder With
>   Items/codingdojo/JavaScript-Mean/angular/twitter/realtime-angular2/node_modules/@types/d3-array/index.d.ts
>   (302,44): ',' expected.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to get this to install correctly in my node server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your npm command have d2 instead of d3. Is that the problem?
Try:

```
npm i @types/d3 --save-dev
```

and

```
npm i d3 --save
```

Comment: Sorry, d2 was a typo.  I had been using d3 for the npm install and have tried both of the suggestions you provided above with the same resulting issue.

Comment: Try to remove your node_modules, clean npm cache and install again. 
Also, could you provide more details? Your package.json and maybe ` /d3-array/index.d.ts (302,44)`.

Comment: I'm trying to run the code from this book:  https://github.com/Matt-Dionis/tweet-dashboard.git. I've run several of my own MEAN projects, but this one is not working for me and I really need to get something from it for a project to work.   I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well.

Comment: The steps I've taking are 1) clone from GitHub 2) run NPM install from root directory